# Sort by Date range asc

Tags: sorting, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I need some quick and simple help with a query.

```
=query('Active Workstreams [update me] 10.2'!B6:L306, "SELECT B,C,D,I,J,L where C > date '"&TEXT(A8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date'"&TEXT(B8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

What and where do I need to add to the order by C asc?

I have tried a few different versions but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=query('Active Workstreams [update me] 10.2'!B6:L306,
 "SELECT B,C,D,I,J,L where C > date '"&TEXT(A8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C <= date'"&TEXT(B8,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' order by C asc ",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

the order of argument is as follows:

```
select  
where   
group by    
pivot   
order by    
limit   
offset  
label   
format  
options
```

while you can skip any of them (yes even `select`) the order must be preserved